# Strange memory behaviour on agenda

Tags: javascript, node.js

I've just started using [agenda](https://github.com/rschmukler/agenda) in a node js app and I find a strange memory behaviour. The memory increase by 200kb after every job execution. Here a simple example that present the same behaviour

```
var Agenda = require('agenda');
var agenda = new Agenda({db: { address: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/my-test-db'}});
agenda.define('say hi', function(job, done) {
  console.log('Hi!!!!')
  done();
});
agenda.every('10 seconds', 'say hi');
agenda.start();
```

Any idea why it happens?